# How to link shared library in shell script?

Tags: shell, command, shared-libraries

I have wrote a simple shell script where I have only mentioned the following line

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/lib/

I want to run one program for which I have to link with this library ,before running the program I am running this shell script ,but after this the program is not working it showing the linking error and when I am doing following line it showing nothing

> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

but,when I am doing it in shell normally ,it is working.

Can any one tell why this shell script is not working.what is the concept behind it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a script for the purpose of modifying environment variables you need to source the script rather than run the script. Running the script starts a new instance of w/e shell is used to run the script, when it returns, all environment variables are back to the way they were before you ran it. Doing "source script.sh" actually runs the commands in the script in your current shell.